# Entity Framework with Mysql not show relations

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have asp.net mvc 4.0 and Ef 5.0 project. 
Now I want to model a **mysql** database which have relations between tables.

When I **generate model from database**  all tables generating but relations don't appear.

How can i generate relations?
Help please thanks..

Comment: "which have relations between tables" how are the relations defined in mySQL? Foreign key constraints?

Comment: Yes @StevenV, relations defined with **Foreign key constraints**